# What are the maximum columns in an Access 2003 query?

Tags: ms-access

What are the maximum allowed number of columns in a query in access 2003?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

255 I believe.  You can check by going to *Help > Specifications > Query* within Access.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, if you ever find yourself asking a question about the maximum hardcoded limit of a technology, it's time to step back and verify that you're taking the right approach.  Perhaps a query against access that's pulling in hundreds or thousands of columns isn't the right approach.

Comment: That's a poor answer.  Perhaps I have data that I am querying which is really wide, or I need to tie a couple of tables together which are all wide.  Often in software you have to do things that may not be the right approach but gets to your end result.

Comment: I think it's a legitimate point to raise, particularly with applications like Access that don't scale very well.

Comment: Access is being used as a quick report generator, something it's really good at.

Comment: Any table or query with number of columns approaching 255 is badly designed and that's the source of the problem, regardless of the database engine in use.

Comment: Sometimes you're forced to bring in data for conversions from other poorly designed systems in order to clean them up. Doesn't mean you are going to place it in production. If you do, it will either show up in poor performance or it just doesn't matter how many columns your table has.

Answer (score 0):

### From Access Help File

Thank you Ben

Number of enforced relationships: 32 per table minus the number of indexes that are on the table for fields or combinations of fields that are not involved in relationships
Number of tables in a query: 32
Number of fields in a recordset: 255
Recordset size: 1 gigabyte
Sort limit: 255 characters in one or more fields
Number of levels of nested queries: 50 
Number of characters in a cell in the query design grid: 1,024
Number of characters for a parameter in a parameter query: 255
Number of ANDs in a WHERE or HAVING clause: 99
Number of characters in an SQL statement: approximately 64,000

Answer (score 0):

Maximum numnber of column that you can add in ms access query is 255 but Let me tell me one thing : 
In access you can make query in two ways

1. Create query in design view
2. Create query by using wizard.

For the first option you will have only a max of 16 columns to add in a query
but using the second option you can add upto 255 columns in your query.

:)