# Does Access query builder limit the number of columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a long query that pulls well over 50 fields.  For some reason Access query builder provides only a limited amount of columns at a time.
[image: no more room]

However, it appears that I can key as many as I like directly into the SQL view.  And eventually the query builder makes more room.  So using the above example, if I add three more fields to the query, the query builder gives me about another ten to work with.

Is there an easier way to extend the number of columns?  Are there other alternatives that I should be considering?

Comment: In earlier versions of access there was an upper limit of 255.  I'm not sure if that limitation still exists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188462/what-are-the-maximum-columns-in-an-access-2003-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just figured it out.  I can easily add more columns using the "Insert Columns" button.
[image: Insert Columns]